# golang program import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts/keystore" build error

Tags: go, ethereum

Please find my golang specifications

- GOOS=linux
- GOARCH=amd64

> go build github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1: build
>   constraints exclude allGo files in
>   /Users/mac/Documents/project/src/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/crypto/secp256k1

Comment: [see this page](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/issues/16818)

Answer (score 1):

Run the command with `CGO_ENABLED=1` to enable the use of cgo when cross compiling.

```
CGO_ENABLED=1 GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build
```